# Xpath scraping further link from subpages?

Tags: php, web-scraping, xpath

I Finally managed to make a script in php for scraping basic elements from other websites. It is super simple. This example shows how to get title and url.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$url = 'http://test123cxqwq12.000webhostapp.com/mainpage.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$title = $xpath->query('/html/body/a/h1');

$source = $xpath->query('/html/body/a/@href');

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($source)-1; $i++) {
$new = $source[$i]->nodeValue;
$text = $title[$i]->nodeValue;
echo "<a href=".$new." target=_blank><img src=".$text."></a>"."</br>";
}
```

Page with results: http://test123cxqwq12.000webhostapp.com/scrap.php

Page to scraping content: http://test123cxqwq12.000webhostapp.com/mainpage.php

Subpage: http://test123cxqwq12.000webhostapp.com/subpage.php

Now I would like to go a step further and take the data from the subpage. So instead of taking source from main page like is right now. I would like to go into this source and take another source (in this example google.com link) from subpage. I'm out of ideas. I would like to ask for some tips, is it possible to do it with xpath in similar way I was doing now?

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution could be to store the URL in a database then apply your Curl and xpath functions to them

```
<?php

function curlGet($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$results = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $results;
}

function returnXPathObject($item) {
    $xmlPageDom = new DomDocument();
    @$xmlPageDom->loadHTML($item);
    $xmlPageXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlPageDom);
    return $xmlPageXPath;
}

$allUrl = $cxn->query("SELECT * FROM yourDatabaseUrl");
$allUrl = $allUrl->fetchAll();   

for ($i = 0; $i<count($allUrl); $i++){
    $url = $allUrl[$i];
    $getDom = curlGet($url);
    $getDomXpath = returnXPathObject($getDom);
    $title = $getDomXpath->query('/html/body/a/h1');
    $source = $getDomXpath->query('/html/body/a/@href');
}
```

I'm not sure about this answer it's just a proposition